# How can I find state level data on NLRB 81a3 cases

Tags: data.gov

I'm having the biggest trouble downloading XML files from the NLRB.  I'm interested in state-level numbers of NLRB ordered reinstatements for 8.1.a.3 ULP cases.

Comment: Have you found an XML file and are having a hard time reading it or are you having a hard time finding the file in the first place?